# What multi-color succulent is this?

Tags: identification, succulents

Received this succulent yesterday from a nursery far away. I have put it in water till now.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Plantnet app suggested it's Aeonium arboreum. Is this right? How should I care for it? Since the stem is so long, can I cut it and plant in soil (because if this is Aeonium, then it likes to be a shallow pot, right?)

Comment: I would guess it is on a long stem because it was an offshoot growing sideways from under a big parent plant. If you don't want a long stem, cut it off cleanly at the length you want and it will grow as a cutting. You only seem to have one miserable little root so far, anyway.

Comment: @alephzero Can you please expand a little bit? I need to keep this in water after cutting it until the roots develop or put it in a gritty succulent mix and water it? If planting in soil, do I need to keep the soil moist all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aeonium arboreum, possibly the variety 'Zwartkop' or 'atropurpureum' so no, it does not need a shallow pot, these can grow up to a metre or more. You won't be sure its Zwartkop until it's had some sun exposure - the leaves lose their black coloration without it, although in very hot and sunny places, they actually prefer a relatively shady spot. I wouldn't cut anything off the stem, unless its starting to show signs of rot from having been in water - there's  a little root there already, although the stem is just a little thicker than one you'd usually choose to propagate from.

Take it out of the water and leave it on its side for a few days somewhere warm and dry until the wound at the bottom has calloused over and looks dry. Then pot up into a mix of sharp  grit mixed with (preferably) soil based potting soil, making sure at least half the stem is above soil level. If you have access to perlite, after gently firming the cutting into the soil, spread a little perlite over the top to help keep the stem dry (or you can use a little sharp grit) then water. Instructions here https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-take-aeonium-cuttings/